# About QThread example in PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt6

## Question

I have some question about `QThread` example in PyQt6, this problem is normal in pyqt6: **QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running**. Solution is add parent class for `QThread` Example. After several times, I have some question.

1. If not add `parent` for `TestThread`, early exit procedure will normal.

```py
# play function
def play(self):
    print("Create a thread")
    self.tt = TestThread()
    self.tt.output_signal.connect(
        self.output_print
    )
    print('create thread success')
    self.tt.start()
```

2. If add `parent` for `TestThread`, early exit procedure will show **QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running**.

```py
def play(self):
    print("Create a thread")
    self.tt = TestThread(parent=self)
    self.tt.output_signal.connect(
        self.output_print
    )
    print('create thread success')
    self.tt.start()
```

3. If `TestThread` as normal variable in `MW`, but add `parent` for it, it will show **QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running**

```py
def play(self):
    print("Create a thread")
    tt = TestThread(parent=self)
    tt.output_signal.connect(
        self.output_print
    )
    print('create thread success')
    tt.start()
```

4. If `TestThread` as normal variable in `MW`,and remove `parent` for it, it will show **QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running** and `QMainWindow` window not show.

```py
# play function
def play(self):
    print("Create a thread")
    tt = TestThread()
    tt.output_signal.connect(
        self.output_print
    )
    print('create thread success')
    tt.start()
```

## Entire Code

Environment: Mac 13, python 3.9.6

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt6.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import sys


class MW(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.play()

    def play(self):
        print("Create a thread")
        self.tt = TestThread(parent=self)
        self.tt.output_signal.connect(
            self.output_print
        )
        print('create thread success')
        self.tt.start()

    def output_print(self, str_):
        print(str_)


class TestThread(QThread):
    output_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

    def run(self) -> None:
        for i in range(10000):
            self.output_signal.emit(f'{i}')
            QThread.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MW()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

## modify

This word(`exit procedure`) is got from translate softaware, so may be it's unexplicit.

In this program, `TestThread` use `pyqtSignal` to print number in `range(10000)`, as general, it will exit until print 9999, but you can use `Meta + q`(Mac) to kill this program.

Comment: Case 4 is expected, because there is no persistent reference to the thread (so it gets *destroyed*); case 3 is probably related to the same issue (the `parent` should take ownership, but QThread may behave slightly differently in the Python context and possibly delete it anyway; case 2 is unclear since it's not clear what you mean by "exit procedure".

Comment: @musicamante `exit procedure` is mean when the procedure is running, you exit it early.

Comment: Sorry but that's a rephrasing, not an explanation. You are not telling what "early" refers to, nor *how* you're trying to exiting, and not even what you mean by "procedure". Please take your time and make it **clear** what you mean by that, as right now nor your code or the question make clear that aspect.

Comment: @musicamante I modify my question, maybe it's explicit.

Comment: So, by "exit procedure" you mean when you try to quit the program? Does the same happen also when trying to use the close button of the window?

Comment: @musicamante Of course, both of them are send kill signal to the program